# How to pass values from form to datatables

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatables

I am playing with laravel and datatables.
[Here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/advance-filter) is the table with filtering option in the form I want to understand.
Basically configured routes and controllers as in the example but cannot dynamically get values from a drop down list below via ajax.

```
<select class="form-control" id="asortment" name="asortment">
<option value="68">A</option>
<option value="5">B</option>
...
```

Javascript responsible for ajax communication:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                url: "{{ route('api.products.index') }}",
                data: function (d) {
                    d.product = $('input[name=product]').val();
                    d.fromDate = $('input[name=fromDate]').val();
                    d.toDate = $('input[name=toDate]').val();
                    d.asortment = $('input[name=asortment]').val();
                },
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Name", },
                { "data": "Type" },
                { "data": "Asortment" },
                { "data": "Margin" }
            ]
        });
    });

    $('#search-form').on('submit', function(e) {
        oTable.draw();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

My API controller looks like this:

```
class APIController extends Controller
{
    public function getProducts(Request $request)
    {
        $product = $request->input('product');
        $fromDate = $request->input('fromDate');
        $toDate = $request->input('toDate');
        $asortment = $request->input('asortment');

        $query = DB::select('exec test.dbo.Products @startDate = ?, @endDate = ?, @asortment = ?, @produkt = ?', [$fromDate, $toDate, $asortment, $product]);

        return datatables($query)->make(true);
    }

}
```

Problem: Ajax takes 3 values (product, fromDate, toDate) but doesn't accept asortment, which is in select form.

I need a little help on why...:)

Comment: replace `$('input[name=asortment]').val();` with `$("#asortment").val();` and give it a try.

Comment: @RutvijKothari It works. Before I tried replacing input with select and no effect. Can you just shortly explain why it is correct now?

Comment: Sorry, I explained in the answer. Comments aren't good way to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Using `$('input[name=asortment]').val();` change it to `$("#asortment").val();` (Pure jQuery way!).

$('input[name=YOUT_NAME]').val(); doesn't work with Radio Button/Select/Checbox.

> val() allows you to pass an array of element values. This is useful
>   when working on a jQuery object containing elements like , , and s inside of a
>   . In this case, the inputs and the options having a value that
>   matches one of the elements of the array will be checked or selected
>   while those having a value that doesn't match one of the elements of
>   the array will be unchecked or unselected, depending on the type. In
>   the case of s that are part of a radio group and
>   s, any previously selected element will be deselected.
>
> ***Setting values using this method (or using the native value property)
>   does not cause the dispatch of the change event.*** For this reason, the
>   relevant event handlers will not be executed. If you want to execute
>   them, you should call **.trigger( "change" )** after setting the value.

This is mentioned in jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2).